# Saving a file to parse from China Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am currently developing in China and the problem lies in this following code; namely, with a VPN, the following code runs smoothly but without the VPN, the problem arises:

```
    let taskInformation = PFObject(className:"TaskInformation")

    let defaultPictureData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "defaultPicture")!, 0.5)
    let pictureFile: PFFile = PFFile(data: defaultPictureData!)!
    taskInformation["pictureFile"] = pictureFile

    taskInformation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            print("The object has been saved.")
        } else {
            print("There was a problem, check error.description")
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try to run this code without a VPN, `taskInformation["pictureFile"] = pictureFile` will leave the app in a state that is not crashing upon nor executing this line. When I comment this line out and run the app without a VPN, the app works smoothly as with a VPN. Is there a different way to save a picture file or is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: what an issue with china..? do you think anything relevant china swift, and PARSE??

Comment: Presumably it will eventually fail with a timeout?

Comment: I mean it works with the VPN but when I get off of it, it doesn't work. Man, so frustrating!!!

Comment: If Parse doesn't work in China (i.e. blocked by the "Great Firewall") or is slow your program is probably will probably hang.

Comment: You should check if your defaultPicture is a available in both targets

Comment: Hmmm... What do you mean both targets?